# getElementsByName won't loop through entire array

Tags: javascript, loops

The following code executes on the press of a button. It works fine alerting one string of the getElementsByName array, but when introduced to a loop, it **still** only alerts the first string value, and nothing more:

```
function checkvals() {

var input = document.getElementsByName('ModuleTitle', 'ModuleCode', 'BuildingName', 'Day');
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= input.length; i++){
alert(input[i].value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `getElementsByName` only accepts one argument, so it's only fetching the first name.

You can build a full collection like this...

```
var names = ['ModuleTitle', 'ModuleCode', 'BuildingName', 'Day'];

var input = [];
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name_els = document.getElementsByName(names[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < name_els.length; j++) {
        input.push(name_els[j]);
    }
}
```

Then loop over the `input` Array, *(or just do your work in the inner loop)*.

---

Additionally, you have a bug.

This...

```
for (i = 0; i <= input.length; i++){
```

should be this...

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
```

...otherwise, you'll go one past the last index.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `getElementsByName` only takes a *single* `name` argument, and returns all elements with that value for their `name` attribute. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName.) If you have multiple `name`s to look up, you'll have to call it multiple times.

Comment: But it still only alerts one value even when I do this:

function checkvals() {

var input = document.getElementsByName('ModuleTitle', 'ModuleCode', 'BuildingName', 'Day');

alert(input[0].value);
alert(input[1].value);
alert(input[2].value);
alert(input[3].value);

}